# Version 4.9.1 wp enqueue script not working as it should

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress to add a cdn , this kind of thing works well with css 
with wp_styles .
It seems to convert the link to the localhost link plus the cdn.
My code echos:

http://tavlin.daniellowes.com/wp-content/plugins/home/aborigi6/public_html/tavlin/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/https:/cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.2.0/aos.js?ver=1.1

It should echo
https:/cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.2.0/aos.js?ver=1.1

Here is the problematic php code code:

```
function aos() { 

        wp_register_script( 'aos', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.2.0/aos.js', array('jquery'), 3.3, true); 
        wp_enqueue_script('aos'); 

    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'aos');
```

Comment: You probably have a url rewrite in a htaccess file somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?php

function aos() { 
    wp_register_script( 'aos', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.2.0/aos.js', array('jquery'), '3.3', true ); 
    wp_enqueue_script('aos'); 
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'aos');

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'aos', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.2.0/aos.js', array('jquery'), 3.3, true); 

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in the code you provided, all must work without any problems. Your js must be enqueued as you want.

The problems may issued by: `.htaccess` rewrited rules, some plugin, which is forcing all your scripts through some filter, the function from your theme/or some code added into your theme files.

We can't provide you more information, because can't see backend part of your website. If you( or somebody else ) didn't added/changed some code from `.php` files, didn't add some js script and didn't add some rules into your `.htaccess` file, than your first step must be to check plugins( plugins, which forcing urls from `http` to `https`, adding some expiration dates, caching content, adding some rules from options, generating cdn urls and etc. ) options, `.htaccess` file, then theme `functions.php` file.

I can guess, that your url changed twice with 2 different functions. First is adding `http://tavlin.daniellowes.com/wp-content/plugins/` to your enqueued script url, and second is adding `home/aborigi6/public_html/tavlin/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/`.

Another way to check, where filter is used( if its done with filter ), is to hook into some other action, like

```
function aos() { 
wp_register_script( 'aos', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.2.0/aos.js', array('jquery'), 3.3, true); 
    wp_enqueue_script('aos'); 

}

add_action('wp_head', 'aos');
```

or to some other hook you need.

Comment: Thank you removing https add putting // worked as the comment bellow //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.2.0/aos.js